# Issue with getting pw_bands output file for ws2

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, band-structure, electronic-structure, density-of-states

[image]

After running the input pw_bands.in file execution is not stopping even after 10hrs , and the output is not updating anything further after 1 min of the output.

Comment: Welcome to our new community! However, you would need to provide your input file and output file in `code` blocks (not as screenshots), for anyone here to help you. The question would get "closed" and then deleted otherwise.

Comment: You can copy your input file and paste it here in between three of ` symbol (usually just below the Esc key in the keyboard). From the screenshot, I have one suggestion that is unnecessary space/line break is discouraged in QE input. Also, from the nature of your output file, it seems that it might be the case that you forgot to add `-inp`/`-in`/`-i`/`<` after pw.x in your command and that's why pwscf is just waiting for the input file.